# How to increase line length in VS Code's pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I've been using the default python linter in VS Code and would like to increase the line length before the linter decides to break up a line. I've tried adding this to settings.json:

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--max-line-length=120",
    ],
```

but the behavior hasn't changed. It's still breaking lines at 80 columns.

Answer (score 3):

Create `.pylintrc` and add

```
[FORMAT]
max-line-length=120
```

Now you can see the max line length shown in problems has turned to be 120:

[image]

Comment: No change after adding those settings and reloading

Comment: @BBrooklyn. I've update my answer, please try again.

Comment: I've tried putting the file at the top of my file system and at the root directory of a project, no change :(

Answer (score 0):

Create `.pylintrc` at the root of your project containing the following:

```
[FORMAT]
max-line-length=120
```

**Don't forget to reload the Window** (i.e. on macOS it is CMD+R). This works fine for me.